# Find broken links to other documents in MS-Office documents (Word)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

In our team we have a shared folder with all the documents. Most documents contain hyperlinks to other documents.

From time to time, we move some files and links get broken.

I need a tool that checks all documents in a specific folder, and shows the broken links to other documents.

We need this mainly for MS-Word 2010, but also for Excel 2010.

What did not work: [AbleBits Link Checker](http://www.ablebits.com/word-links-checker/index.php) does not find the broken links.

Comment: Have you considered just writing a quick macro to do this?

Comment: A VBA macro? Could this scan a full directory tree? (I dont' have VBA skills)

Comment: Yes, have a search on the internet and you might find a similar macro where you can start from.

Answer (score 0):

Additional software that you might check is ReplaceMagic. It suppport changes in Word, Excel, Visio, PowerPoint, Project, PDF and Windows Shortcuts. In case of Excel you can also make changes in VBA.

Of course, ReplaceMagic ([www.replacemagic.com](http://www.replacemagic.com)) can check links and provide reporting what is broken and what works.

Application is multithreaded so performances are excellent and you can set parent folder and instruct processing in all subfolders also.

Additionally ReplaceMagic is not Office dependant :)

Comment: SuperUser does not really accept software recommendations as answers. If you could offer ways to track this in Excel I think including a recommended software as an alternative would be okay but this reads more like a sales pitch than an answer.

Comment: What you are giving the question is just a shopping recommendation. Does not add value. Consider editing your answer or post this as comment